# Symfony 2 custom filter

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I want to create custom filter that calculates difference between two dates.
I follow [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) and create filter source:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('auctionLenght', array($this, 'auctionLenght')),
    );
}

public function auctionLenght($creDate,$expDate)
{
  $datetime1 = new \DateTime($creDate);
  $datetime2 = new \DateTime($expDate);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  $data = date('Y-m-D', $interval);
  return $data;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'eforma_extension';
}
```

Now I want to use it in template:

```
{{entity.creDate |auctionLenght(entity.expDate)}}
```

But I get error all the time:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given")

I tried to pass \DateTime type-hint in public function auctionLenght(\DateTime $creDate,\DateTime  $expDate) but it is not working. How can I repair this? Filter is registered proper because simple add to string filter working well.

Answer (score 3):

If `entity` is a Doctrine ORM Entity, then you probably already have `DateTime` objects from it, and you could remove the two lines instantiating them, which should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), especially [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) one. `public DateTime::__construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )` receives a string (default to `string $time = "now"`) arguemtn not an object..

You can format your `creDate` and `exprDate` objects to string in filter function and pass them to datetime:
example:

```
public function auctionLenght($creDate,$expDate)
{
  $creString = $creDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $expString = $expDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  ....

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well I put my data from entity. entity.creDate is Doctrine DateTime object. Is that change some think ? I try Your solution and replay.

Comment: Its one simple line if data are data pulled as Doctrine. return $creDate->diff($expDate)->format('%a days'); Thanks for help

Comment: @user2217288 _ShonM_ already answered your question, Doctrine writes as datetime object and fetches as datetime object if you set its type as datetime, that's why you don't need to format, pass them to DateTime object, you can use them directly.. +1 to his answer from me..